# Blender 2.8 more gizmo!

Tags: modeling, interface

I like the new gizmos in Blender 2.8!

I would like to see them more often while working. But I’ve been using Blender for a long time and I use shortcuts. For example, “R” key for rotating and “G” key for moving. When I use shortcuts, gizmos don’t work. I tried to configure shortcuts for gizmos, but nothing changed.

So now: I choose Cube - press “R”, “Z” - rotate the mouse or choose the needed figure - confirm the operation.

What I want: I choose Cube - press “R”, “Z” - rotate the mouse or choose the needed figure and here the needed gizmo appears from the T-board from the left (if I press “G”, the gizmo of moving appears) - with all this going on when I’m rotating the mouse, the gizmo is changing after the mouse or figures I press.

I would be thankful for your support and I’m waiting for your help :)
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please don't ask the same question twice. If you need to edit a question you can use the [edit] link below it. Seeing as you have corrected the grammatical issues in this one I have voted to close your previous question instead of this one.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, yes it would make sense to make the gizmo appear when you press <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd>, but it doesn't seem to be the case, you need to click on the *Move*, *Rotate* and *Scale* button on the Tools panel, which is a bit tedious.

One thing that is useful to know though is that you can choose to have the gizmo always displayed when you click on the gizmo's options on the bottom. In my opinion it's much more natural to keep it anytime like it was the case in 2.7.

[image]

Comment: I think there are also a lot of people, myself included, who prefer to work without the gizmos visible ever... But it would make sense to leave them on during operations if they are turned on. As well as the axis indicator in the corner, that for some reason now disappears the only moment someone might actually want to see it - after pressing G/R/S during the transform operation, when it's often time to constrain some axis and one forgets what axis is what direction in relation to the view...

Comment: Yes I agree, the second part of my comment is just a non perfect solution

Comment: Since we are on the subject, I would like to invite everybody to tell the devs about our struggles with the disappearing axis :) https://devtalk.blender.org/t/disappearing-3d-viewport-axis-when-using-transform-hotkeys-2-8/2355/14

Answer (score 1):

You could right-click the items in the toolbar, and change their shortcuts to g,r,and s.  Then when you flip between g,r,s the manipulator will always show.

Comment: .. UV'd, but I wouldn't personally choose to do that. Something quicker than the default Shift-Spacebar + xxx, maybe, but I wouldn't want to cover the basic transforms.